# The .pdb symbol won't load even though I added settings of the Tools -> Debugging

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

[image]I work on my projects, but all of the code that I've been made won't run because of the Unloaded .pdb symbols. Tell me what should I do:(

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool showLogTransformedHuMoments = true;
    string filename("D:\KULIAH\TA\database\F1\frame_v_thres.jpg");
    Mat im1 = imread(filename, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    threshold(im1, im1, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

    Moments moment = moments(im1, false);

// Calculate Hu Moments calculates the Hu moment
double huMoments[7];
HuMoments(moment, huMoments);

// Print Hu Moments
cout << filename << ": ";

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (showLogTransformedHuMoments)
    {
        // Log transform Hu Moments to make squash the range
        cout << -1 * copysign(1.0, huMoments[i]) * log10(abs(huMoments[i])) << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        // Hu Moments without log transform.
        cout << huMoments[i] << " ";
    }
}
// One row per file
cout << endl;
}
```

this is the error:

```
'matchshapes.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'matchshapes.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'matchshapes.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\atig6txx.dl
```

Comment: You don't need it at this step. This is not a reason why you code won't run.

Comment: but there is no error in my code

Comment: can you tell me?

Comment: i just attach the code that  i used, would be so happy if you want to tell me whats the error

Comment: How far can you go through the code line with [F10]?

Comment: Those aren't errors. And those are system DLLs. I assure you, you don't need their PDB files.